# What are the dynamics of a rope wrapping around a pole of given radius?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, home-experiment, experimental-technique

Suppose we drop a mass m from an initial angle $\theta_o$ connected to the pole of radius r with a rope of initial length $l_o$. As the system is released, the rope wraps around the pole, decreasing the radius of the rotation. To describe the whole thing, I referred to the dynamics shown in this paper: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/apps/vlPendulum.pdf . But compared to the experiment, the wrapping is too fast. Could damping be an important factor? And how on earth could one measure the damping constant for such a system?

Comment: the constant change of the position of the rotational axis could of course also be a problem